# Can I wake up iPhone by double tapping the screen?

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake

Can I wake up an iPhone/iPad by double tapping the screen without hacking/installing Cydia?

Comment: I think there was an app that use the hardware to recognize a "knock", but i don't now the name of it. It's not possible to enable this in settings.

Comment: You could suggest it to Apple and maybe they'll make it an option for a future version of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this natively as part of the built-in functions of iOS.  There are a few apps that allows knocking, one is called **[MacID](https://macid.co)**.  I've used it for a few years and the developer is very responsive to support issues.

Comment: Isn't OP asking for waking up the iphone or ipad rather than unlocking a macOS device?